automate image deployment using PXE
I want to create a image creation and deployment solution on network using PXE for windows.
I know I need to create a PXE server for that - I am using this microsoft doc to try to create a PXE server - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/configure-a-pxe-server-to-load-windows-pe
I already have an image created to be deployed and am able to deploy it successfully but it requires human intervention.
Is it possible to do the image deployment without human intervention?
